# Export to CSV setting the decimal separator

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, decimal-point

I have data I want to export to CSV from PowerShell. I use `ConvertTo-Csv` to create the data and then pipe it out to a file, works fine, but...

**My data gets written with a comma as *decimal* separator. I need this to be a "." point.**

There must be something I'm overlooking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `NumberFormat` property of the current culture:

```
(Get-Culture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = '.'
```

Comment: `decimal separator`

Comment: Yes, it's culture dependent. Compare `[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('de-DE').NumberFormat` and `[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US').NumberFormat` for example

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Does not work with PS7 Core! ``SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "NumberDecimalSeparator": "Instance is read-only."``